# The specified deps.json does not exist in Asp.netCore2.1 Project

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1

I tried running add-migration to create database for my .netCore2.1 project. i have 2 project . One is a Business Object Layer that contains my Model Classes while the other is DAL ( Data access Layer ) that contains my DBContext. I've Added the DLL of my BOL later to my DAL and i tried generating Database but "debs.json file not exist" keeps coming out in my Console"

Kindly help me it's frustrating me already

Answer (score 6):

I posted this question and after 3 days of active research and trial and error i finally came up with a solution which i thought could help my fellow Developers.

The problem is a Path issue. my project folder was inside \\Mac\User...Document\VisualStudio2017\project\

The above path could not be located for reasons unknown to me so i moved the project to this Path

C:\User...Document\VisualStudio2017\project\

The only difference is i changed the root directory from \\Mac to  C:\

then it was solved no more error

i hope this is able to help some people out there

Comment: I had the same issue when my project was stored on a UNC path \\<serverName> after moving the project to my local HDD the issue went away. Thanks

Comment: Are you using a Mac? , I tried to relocate the project to the Desktop but no luck on mac.